# VB.NET Copy File with Foldertree from known parameters

Tags: vb.net, file-io, vb.net-2010

I got a list with full file path as example:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\doc1.docx
C:\Backup\passwords.pdf
...
```

I would like to copy them with a vb.net code to a destination set in a textbox but keeping the folder tree alive. As example I would like to copy all files to D:\Backup this should be like this:

```
D:\Backup\Users\User1\Desktop\doc1.docx
D:\Backup\Backup\passwords.pdf
```

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Use the System.IO.Path class to compose directory paths.

Comment: I can get the Path with getDirectory so it ends with: "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\" but how can I get my program to create Folder Users->User1->Desktop in my destination folder?

Comment: Use Directory.CreateDirectory().  It is smart enough to create all required sub-directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code example is complete.  You should be able to substitute a string array in place of the fileList variable without too much trouble since .NET can foreach a string array in the same way as I am doing it here.  The rest of the code is pretty straight forward.  I create the destPath variable, then the path itself if it does not already exist.  Then we move on to creating the destination filename and then calling copy.

This code will process a list of path complete filenames or an array of strings where each string is a path complete filename.  I have not tested to see if it will create a pathname more than 1 level deep, so you'll need to test that scenario.

To acheive your intention of keeping the entire path alive then just change the source folder variable to c: and it should work the same.  The only use of source folder is to replace the specified source folder with an empty string in preparation to append it to the destination path, so that should do what you want.

Cheers!

```
Try
        Dim fileList As New List(Of String)
        Dim sourceFolder As String = "c:\Users\User1"
        fileList.Add("c:\Users\User1\file1.docx")
        fileList.Add("c:\Users\User1\subfolder1\file2.docx")
        Dim destinationPath As String = "c:\backup"
        For Each file As String In fileList
            Dim destPath As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", destinationPath, IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file).Replace(sourceFolder, ""))
            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(destPath) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
            Dim destFile As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", destinationPath, file.Replace(sourceFolder, ""))
            IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, False)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Dim FileName As String = "c:\blaat\yadda.txt"
    If Not Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName))
    End If
```

And ofcourse you'll put this in a try catch block...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I had a timelimit to finish everything here so i got my own working solution which is making following from my paths:

```
Dim destinationpath As String
    Dim folderpath As String
    If cb_foldertree.Checked = True Then
        For Each item In FileArray
            destinationpath = txt_destination.Text + Path.GetDirectoryName(item).Remove(0, 2) + "\" + Path.GetFileName(item)
            folderpath = txt_destination.Text + Path.GetDirectoryName(item).Remove(0, 2)
            If Directory.Exists(folderpath) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath)
            End If
```

This makes sure I only create the folders with relevant files in it so no empty folders there. Would you suggest to use try catch method here? What could happen exept of no rights to write?